# Are questions on measurement uncertainty on uncertainty off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I will soon be doing some work on uncertainty in image processing type techniques (specifically surface texture) and have some questions on various measurement uncertainty related topics. Is this a good place to ask such questions?

I haven't worked out exactly what the questions are yet (I need to think some more about what I understand) but I guess they fall into 2 categories:

1) questions about the fundamentals of uncertainty (linerisation, propagation, etc.)

2) more hardware based questions (why do we need to care about certain effects etc.)

My gut instinct is that 1) is probably fine but 2) less so.

If signal processing isn't the right place for these sorts of questions can anyone recommend where would be better?

Answer (score 1):

I think the uncertainty question is probably OK.

The hardware questions probably belong on the [Electrical Engineering SE site.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)